# Stackbuilder for Postgres 16 does not give an option for pgagent

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I am installing Postgres 16  on Windows 11 Pro Laptop and  there is no option to install PgAgent, all other options are there - any feedback

Comment: PgAgent is not part of PostgreSQL, it's an additional piece of software that runs as a deamon/service. If you expect it to be part of the PostgreSQL installer you used, contact the maintainer of this installer.

Answer (score 0):

As the PgAdmin site suggests its not a part of the installation anymore.

You can download, as per your version and OS the installer, the stackbuilder.

The stackbuilder will let you install pgAgent.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

For debian based packages you can perhaps use apt to install pgagent.
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent-apt/

Comment: That is what I am not seeing an option to install pgagent as one of the options

Comment: I tried on Windows 2019 server  and not seeing that option either

Comment: Also tried on a Windows 2022, same result

Comment: Guess I may  have to build from Source code

Comment: what do you mean when you download and install, you dont see pgAgent in the stackbuilder ? https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1258698
and in Stackbuilder if you choose Remote Installation you won't see it in the list..

Comment: I tried using local install on Postgres 16 server and why should I install remote

Comment: not sure why we have to do remote install, i tried locally

Comment: Thats what I meant, pgagent shows up when you select a local installation. It does not show up when you select remote.
Also if local installation don't show up, then do a reinstall of postgres because the registry was no good for the stackbuilder and re-install postgres fixed..

Comment: When I initially downloaded, I did not Windows 2022 install for Postgres, however the installation succeeded but not the pgagent,  Uninstalled postgres today,  when I went to download, I saw the windows 2022 install option on postgres download and I now am able to see the pgagent install in pgagent